# Is UK residency required for a Canadian Working Holiday Visa?

Tags: visas, canada, uk-citizens, working-holiday

I am an UK citizen by way of my parent. I do not live in the UK but I do have a UK passport and have had one since I was a child (renewed in between).

In order to qualify for the "Working Holiday Visa", there was once a residency requirement of **3 years of continual UK presence**. However [this requirement was recently removed](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/united_kingdom-royaume_uni/experience_canada_experience/FAQ.aspx#uk2-7) and there is no longer a need to prove 3 years of residency. I've looked around the site and it is somewhat unclear (to me) if residency itself is no longer required or if only the 3 year requirement had changed.

**Question: Is UK residency still required to qualify for a Working Holiday Visa or is being a citizen sufficient?**

Comment: To be clear, you're wanting to go on a working holiday in Canada, right? Where do you live now?

Comment: That would be correct. Currently, Barbados (dual-citizenship).

Answer (score 2):

The following is copied from the Canadian Government website.

"To apply for a work permit at this visa office, you must be legally admitted to ***or*** a ***citizen*** of a country that is served by this visa - office.http://www.cic.gc.ca/English/information/offices/apply-where.asp "

Barbados *and* UK are both on that list. So in other words, according to the Government of Canada, you are allowed to apply, just by being a citizen.

Here is a link to the website which has more information and a contact phone number to call for more information about this.

http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/united_kingdom-royaume_uni/visas/work_temp_travailler.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am aware of this but a "Working holiday" visa is not the same as a workers permit.  A workers permit (+ a temporary visa/passport), 
allows one to work in Canada but with several limitations such as: 
Work type + exp, Location, Job offer before applying (if I understand correctly), etc.  A "Working holiday" is a specialised visa which is: Limited to certain countries; Must  be <= 30 yrs; 2x per lifetime(previously 1); Allows benefactor to work+live in the Canada for 1 yr, without limits on job type, exp, location, etc.; Uses a less restricted form of work permit.

Comment: More on "Working holiday": http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/united_kingdom-royaume_uni/experience_canada_experience/working_holiday-vacances_travail.aspx

Comment: The second link lists the eligibility criteria, which it seems you satisfy. You are a UK citizen, residency doesn't come into it.

Comment: I would be inclined to agree with you but seeing it was previously a requirement makes me unsure . Furthermore, in the FAQ it responds to [a similar the question](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/united_kingdom-royaume_uni/experience_canada_experience/faq.aspx#uk2-8) by saying, "If your **usual place of residence is the United Kingdom** and you are temporarily out of the country, you may apply from the country where you are...". This could be interpreted as no need of _continual_ residency but there must be _some_ residency. Thus it remains unclear.